# MySQL on Amazon RDS throwing LockTimeoutException under load

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are currently debugging strange behaviour on MySQL (5.6.21) database deployed on Amazon RDS.

Beginning from a particular date (namely 12 Nov 2014) we observe massive `org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException` exception from our Spring application. Few things happen near that date:

1. Amazon upgraded MySQL deployments from 5.6.20 to 5.6.21.
2. In one of our tables, we've added 3 additional columns of nullable `DATETIME` type.

We've doubled `lock_wait_timeout` parameter value, but it didn't bring any significant results (probably event made the situation worse, since much more locks appeared).

It start to hurt really bad under more or less significant load. In `SHOW PROCESSLIST` I can see a lot of long running `update` queries, which updates exactly those `DATETIME` fields.